# MongoDB index is not being used

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of questions with index on modified.

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
      "modified" : 1
  },
  "name" : "modified_1",
  "ns" : "app23568387.questions",
  "background" : true,
  "safe" : null
}
```

But when I query the questions with modified field, mongo does not use this index.

```
db.questions.find({modified: ISODate("2016-07-20T20:58:20.662Z")}).explain(true);
```

It returns

```
{
  "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
  "isMultiKey" : false,
  "n" : 0,
  "nscannedObjects" : 19315626,
  "nscanned" : 19315626,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 19315626,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 19315626,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 384889,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 43334,
  "allPlans" : [ 
      {
          "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
          "isMultiKey" : false,
          "n" : 0,
          "nscannedObjects" : 19315626,
          "nscanned" : 19315626,
          "scanAndOrder" : false,
          "indexOnly" : false,
          "nChunkSkips" : 0
      }
  ],
  "server" : "c387.candidate.37:10387",
  "filterSet" : false,
  "stats" : {
      "type" : "COLLSCAN",
      "works" : 19624020,
      "yields" : 384889,
      "unyields" : 384889,
      "invalidates" : 3,
      "advanced" : 0,
      "needTime" : 19315627,
      "needFetch" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "docsTested" : 19315626,
      "children" : []
  }
}
```

When I use `hint()`, mongo throws an error `bad hint`.
I have another collection of folders which has exactly the same index and the query uses the index. (returns `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor modified_1"` for `explain()`)

What could be the difference between questions and folders? Is it possible that the index is "broken" even though `getIndexes()` returns it? If so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Could you run that query with `.explain("allPlansExecution")` and then update your quesiton with the entire explain plan output. The essential parts are the chosen plan and the rejected plan sections since these will show us **why** MongoDB did not choose the `modified_1` index. Also, this:  "When I use hint(), mongo throws an error bad hint" suggests that there is no index with the name you supplied to the `hint()` method.

Comment: @glytching I updated the question with the result. (Since our db version is 2.6, I had to pass `true`.) `modified_1` is not in `allPlans`. Does this mean, the index does not exist even though it returns in `getIndexes`?

Comment: @Satoko MongoDB 2.6 has been deprecated for more than **2 years** now. Consider upgrading to version 3.2 at least, and see if the problem persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your index is not completely built in background. You can check this by using db.currentOp() command:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.currentOp/#currentop-index-creation

Also check the mongod.log to see any error on the index building process.

The simple way to fix is to drop the index and create it again

Comment: That's a possibility. The inconsistency between (a) the `bad hint` response and (2) the statement that this index is returned by `getIndexes()` strongly suggests an issue with the index creation process. A related suggestion: if the OP is querying a replicaset with eventual consistency and the query is hitting a secondary then the issue _might_ be that the index has not built successfully on the _secondary_.

Comment: @glytching Yes. I had been only using secondary to run the query. I tried `explain()` on primary, it returned `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor modified_1"`. Later primary and secondary were switched and that caused index to be built again(?). Now both have and use index for the query. Thank you.